# Snowpark SQL compilation error: unexpected '-' in Role name

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpark

When trying to connect to Snowpark using the session method below with role, database, schema, and warehouse names, there is a SQL compilation error with the role name since it contains dashes.

```
dbname = "MY_DB"
schemaname = "MY_SCHEMA"
warehouse = "MY_WH"

read_session.sql(r"USE ROLE MY-SNOWFLAKE-ROLE").collect()
read_session.sql(f"USE WAREHOUSE {warehouse}").collect()
read_session.sql(f"USE DATABASE {dbname}").collect()
read_session.sql(f"USE SCHEMA {dbname}.{schemaname}").collect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The role has to be contained in double quotes while your entire USE statement needs to be within single quotes.

```
dbname = "MY_DB"
schemaname = "MY_SCHEMA"
warehouse = "MY_WH"

read_session.sql(r'USE ROLE "MY-SNOWFLAKE-ROLE"').collect()
read_session.sql(f"USE WAREHOUSE {warehouse}").collect()
read_session.sql(f"USE DATABASE {dbname}").collect()
read_session.sql(f"USE SCHEMA {dbname}.{schemaname}").collect()
```